# Get last clicked item id

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("*").click(function () {             
              alert($(this).attr('id').toString());                
        });
    });
```

And on Page i have something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<script language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="div1">Some stuff
    <div id="div2">Some other stuff
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />        
        <div id="div3">More stuff
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />        
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

If i click something it works fine, but it alerts me three times(or more).
For example:
I click button2. Alertbox appears with button2.id, then with div3.id, div2.id etc. It shows me all id's under that button. 
If i try to store this id to variable like this:

```
     var storedId = $(this).attr('id').toString();
```

it stores the last one.That means i get the id of form1.

How can i get the first id? The id of clicked button or clicked label or whatever i have on my page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to stop event propagation up the DOM tree so parent items don't see the same event.  In jQuery, you can do that with `e.stopPropagation()`:

```
$("*").click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr('id').toString());                
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

FYI, this is a really inefficient way to do this.  You would do it better like this with a single event handler that takes advantage of event bubbling and catches the bubbled click events at the document and examines them in just this one place:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id);                
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should stop event propagation with [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$("*").click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).attr("id").toString());
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Method *prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.*

Answer (score 2):

The event bubbles, so it will show the id of each element that it bubbles through.

Use the [`stopPropagation` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to keep the event from bubbling:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("*").click(function (e) {             
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert($(this).attr('id').toString());                
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered that you can screen the rest of the "useless" events out by stopping their propagation. +1, for this situation, I think that is entirely correct. However, I think there is a better approach that you can use other than using the * selector.

`$("*").click()` uses the [*All Selector ("*")*](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/). When the *all selector* (*) is used it attaches that event to every element on the page. Using this approach is not ideal (performance hits, bad practice, overly complex) unless you have a reason to handle a click event for *every* element on the page (possible, but highly unlikely).

A better approach would be to just assign click events to individual elements (kind of the web standard).

So, if given this scenario

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />        
<div id="div3">More stuff
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />        
    </div>
</div>
```

use two event handlers (one for each button)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function () {             
          alert($(this).attr('id').toString());//note that this.id will also work                
    });
    $("#Button2").click(function () {             
          alert($(this).attr('id').toString());                
    });
});
```

Although this approach requires more event definitions, it makes up for that by easily providing unique event handling per element, more readable code, and better separation of concerns.

Comment: I can write functions for every item on this small example, but i have large dynamic page. That's why i needed this solution. But anyway, thanks for answering. :) stopPropagation() worked well for me. :)