# jQuery - Get first item from bubbling. Get bubble order or id when bubbling

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

My last question was here: [Get last clicked item id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444997/get-last-clicked-item-id) and there was good answers but i still have a problem.

I have function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("*").click(function () {             
          alert($(this).attr('id').toString());                
    });
});
```

And on page i have something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<script language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"><script>
<div id="div1">Some stuff
  <div id="div2">Some other stuff
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />        
    <div id="div3">More stuff
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />        
    </div>
 </div>
```

When Alertbox appears i can store value of clicked item like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("*").click(function (e) {             
      alert($(this).attr('id').toString());  
      var value = $(this).attr('id').toString();                
      e.stopPropagation();  //Stop Propagation            
   });
});
```

But here is the problem. When i stop propagation my other scripts doesn´t fire anymore.
Can i get somehow the bubble order or id? Can i do something like this?:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("*").click(function (e) {    
       if(e.target == this[0])
       {         
         alert($(this).attr('id').toString()); 
         var value = $(this)[0].attr('id').toString();             
       }
       //e.stopPropagation();  //I have to get first value from bubbling without stopPropagation     
 });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without brackets. `if(ev.target === this){`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution, not a perfect solution and little hacky but works, you can tweak it as per your requirement -  [JSFIDDLE IS HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/anmolsaraf/39ssx/) ,

```
var clickArr = [], counter = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("*").click(function (e) {             

  if($(this).attr('id')) {      
  var val = $(this).attr('id').toString();
  clickArr[counter++] = val;
  }
  if(this.tagName == 'BODY') {
   val = clickArr[0];
   counter = 0;
   alert('result is ' + val);
  }
  //e.stopPropagation();  //Stop Propagation            
});
});​
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks, it worked, almost fine :P. 
When i save that value to some label text and on other button try to trigger to that saved value(button1 or button2) i have to push twice. If i try to alert that saved value from other button it shows me first time empty value and then the right one.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, why not just

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicked;

    $('body').click(function(ev){
       clicked = ev.target.id;
    });
});
```